# QTableViewWidget insertRow with ordered tables adding content to the wrong row

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidgetitem

I have a procedure that adds a new row at the end of a QTableViewWidget and fills it with data in this way:

```
    #Add new row
    table.insertRow(table.rowCount())

    #Fill the row
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,iterationNumber)
    self.tableOptimization.setItem(table.rowCount()-1, 0, item)

    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,total)
    self.tableOptimization.setItem(table.rowCount()-1, 1, item)
```

The problem is that if you order the table clicking in any of the columns, the new added row is no longer the last one so the setItem is setting the current last row elements.

Is there any way to solve this? Fill the data before adding? Keep a reference to the inserted row?

Answer (score 0):

I know if I was doing this in C++, I would create the row beforehand and then append it, but it appears that's not possible in Python.

Also, here's what the documentation says:

> If you want to enable sorting in your table widget, do so after you have populated it with items, otherwise sorting may interfere with the insertion order (see setItem() for details).

So I'd recommend turning off sorting, appending the item, then turning it back on. Or if that causes visual problems, just enumerate the rows until you find one that's empty. It's messy but I think it's the best you can do.